# How can I fix my C code that works on desktop but not in rar file?

Tags: c, file-io, rar

The following is my C code for file operations. I have to extract both of them into one rar file. They work on desktop but in rar the second code creates an empty txt. How can I make them work in rar file?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    int number[100];
    fp = fopen("numbers.txt", "w");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        number[i] = rand() % 1000;
        fprintf(fp, "%d\n", number[i]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    
    return 0;
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    FILE *fp1;
    int number, count;
    
    fp = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");
    fp1 = fopen("numbers2.txt", "w");
    
    while (!feof(fp)) {
        count = 0;
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &number);
        for (int i = 2; i < number / 2; i++) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
                count++;
            } 
        }
        if (count == 0 && number >= 2) {
            fprintf(fp1, "%d\n", number);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp1);
    return 0;
}
```

I created a text file that contained random 100 numbers in the first code and exported the prime ones to another text file in the second code.

Comment: OT: Please see [Why is `while ( !feof (file) )` always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Always check that `fopen` does not return a file pointer  `NULL`.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by *I have to extract both of them into one rar file* etc.  Can you expand on this **rar** business: do you want to write the initial file into a **rar** archive and later read it back from the archive while updating it to include the second file?

Comment: Perhaps none of the 100 numbers happen to be prime.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for the advice.The numbers are the same everytime but it doesn't work only when they are in rar so it's not possible.

Comment: @chqrlie Rar is just the format that requested for us to send our assignments .After writing the codes as i said, i want to storage them in a rar file.I hope i can explain the situation correctly.

Comment: @Beyza: just create the archive from the project files including the text files after you complete the assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to deal with files stored in an archive, the simplest method is to use the `system` function:

- when you are done creating the **numbers.txt** file, add the file to the archive with `system("rar a archive.rar numbers.txt")`, then remove the file with `remove("numbers.txt")`
- to extract the file from the archive, use `system("rar e archive.rar numbers.txt")`

Regarding your code:

- do not use `feof()` to test for end of file, check the return value of `fscanf()` instead.
- always check for `fopen` failuresand report meaningful messages.

Here are modified versions:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("numbers.txt", "w");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot create %s: %s\n",
                "numbers.txt", strerrror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        fprintf(fp, "%d\n", rand() % 1000);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    system("rar a archive.rar numbers.txt");
    remove("numbers.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

and

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    FILE *fp1;
    int number, count;

    system("rar e archive.rar numbers.txt");
    fp = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot extract %s: %s\n",
                "numbers.txt", strerrror(errno));
        return 1;
    }
    fp1 = fopen("numbers2.txt", "w");
    if (fp1 == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot create %s: %s\n",
                "numbers2.txt", strerrror(errno));
        remove("numbers.txt");
        return 1;
    }
    
    while (fscanf(fp, "%d", &number) == 1) {
        if (number >= 2) {
            int isprime = 1;
            for (int i = 2; i > number / i; i++) {
                if (number % i == 0) {
                    isprime = 0;
                    break;
                } 
            }
            if (isprime) {
                fprintf(fp1, "%d\n", number);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(fp1);
    system("rar a archive.rar numbers2.txt");
    remove("numbers.txt");
    remove("numbers2.txt");
    return 0;
}
```